# Problem with using change of global variable in loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a global variable, that I want to change in a for-loop and use it later outside of 'for'

I wanted to write code to correct surname and name. For example:
user: NICK WATERSON ... code: Nick Waterson
user: nick waterson ... code: Nick Waterson
user: nIcK wAtErSoN ... code: Nick Waterson

```js
let fTab = 0;
Register: while (true) {
  var name = prompt('Your fullname:', '');

  for (let i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
    if (name.charAt(i) == ' ') {
      fTab = i;
      break Register;
    }
  }

  alert('Error!!')
}

name.toLowerCase();
alert('Your name is ' + name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.substr(1, fTab) + name.charAt(i + fTab).toUpperCase() + name.substr(fTab + 2));
```

Program returns nothing, because can't find value of 'fTab'

Comment: Does it alert with “error”?

Comment: What if you replace `let` with `var`?

Comment: This seems like an excessively complicated way to `split` a string on a space.

Comment: The error message says `i` is undefined because you make a typo and wrote `i` on the last line instead of `fTab`.

Comment: I am getting "*Uncaught ReferenceError: **`i`** is not defined*". The global `fTab` variable works just fine. Did you mean `1` instead of `i`?

Comment: [You would deliberately mangle McLeod Bethel-Thompson's name?](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: Plz accept as an answer if it has resolved your issue.

Answer (score 1):

As @Quentin   mentioned in his comment, You are using an complex way to make the name in TitleCase.
You can use following way, it is easy to read and concise.

```js
let name  = prompt('Your fullname:', '');

let correctedName = name.split(' ')
   .map(first => first[0].toUpperCase() +    first.substr(1).toLowerCase())
   .join(' ');
   
   console.log(correctedName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Program works fine for me, just replace `i + fTab` with `1 + fTab` in the last line:

```
alert('Your name is ' + name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.substr(1, fTab).toLowerCase() + name.charAt(1 + fTab).toUpperCase() + name.substr(fTab + 2).toLowerCase());
```

Answer (score 0):

replace in alert line `i + fTab` with `1 + fTab` **AND** `name = name.toLowerCase();`

```
let fTab = 0;
Register: while (true) {
  var name = prompt('Your fullname:', '');

  for (let i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
    if (name.charAt(i) == ' ') {
      fTab = i;
      break Register;
    }
  }

  alert('Error!!')
}

name = name.toLowerCase();
alert('Your name is ' + name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.substr(1, fTab) + name.charAt(fTab + 1).toUpperCase() + name.substr(fTab + 2));
```